# Unresolved references with list in Python

Tags: python, function, debugging, pycharm

I am not entirely sure whether or not this behavior is to be expected or not, but it is definitely quite strange. When you have some code like this:

```
def a_function():
    if a_list != some_other_list:
        print(a_list)
```

It works fine and I had no issue with it. However, if you change it to:

```
def a_function():
    if a_list != some_other_list:
        a_list = some_other_list
```

Suddenly, a problem occurs where it says that `a_list` on line 2 is an unresolved reference. Why should what is in the if statement affect whether `a_list` can be resolved? Is this kind of thing normal? Is it perhaps a bug in Python 3.6.1 or PyCharm (Community Edition 2017.1.5)? Any help on clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comparison is done with ==, not with =.

Comment: Can you post the full code (definition of `a_list` and `some_other_list`)? Your 2nd line (modified) would generate a _SyntaxError_, but according to you it doesn't (so the `=` might be a typo?).

Comment: Line `3` is the replacing the `print()`. When you assign to `a_list` it is trying to create a local `a_list`, which means your use of `a_list` in the comparison now fails. Doing `global a_list` on the first line of the function would fix this but you really should look into passing and returning values into the function vs. global variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you just access variables that are not local to your function everything works fine as long as they are found somewhere in the outer scopes. But as soon as you assign to a variable it becomes local to your function. Python won't look in the outer scopes for the variable name anymore. So when you include:

```
a_list = some_other_list
```

The line:

```
a_list != some_other_list
```

will fail because it doesn't look for `a_list` outside your function anymore and if you define it later in the function it's an `UnboundLocalError` or similar.

I did go into more details in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940757/5393381) if you're interested.

---

In case you just wanted to compare for equality change `=` (assignment) to `==` (equality check).

Comment: So python first differentiates the local variables based on the assignments in the fun before executing the function. even if the assignment is within if condition?

Comment: yes, even if it would be in an unreachable `if False:` block inside the function :) Of course arguments of the function are also local :)

Answer (score 1):

edit: in python, if you assign a variable inside the scope of the function then it becomes a local variable. so `a_list` becomes local when you `a_list = some_other_list` and Python tells you by throwing the Unresolved Reference Error.

---

also, the if statement expects an expression that returns a boolean value.

`a_list = some_other_list` simply set `some_other_list` to refrence the same memory address as `some_other_listequal` which does notreturn a boolean.

However `a_list == some_other_list` performace a comparison that returns a boolean of `True` or `False` to indicate the value equality of two variables.

Comment: Line 3 is the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between `=` and `==` in python.

`a = b` is assigning the value of b to the variable a.

`a == b` is comparing the value of a to the value of b.

In your case you want to use `==` which compares the two values and returns `True` if they are the same value, otherwise it will return `False`.

Comment: Line 3 is the print() function.